# Running multiple tests features with cucumber for java selenium serenity tests

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, end-to-end, cucumber-serenity

I have following config to run the files in specific folder for java cucumber config (selenium tests).

```
 
package com.hero.selenium.test;

import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import net.serenitybdd.cucumber.CucumberWithSerenity;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        monochrome = true,
        features = {"src/test/resources/features/"},
        glue = {"com.hero.selenium.test.stepdefinitions"}
)
public class MainRunner {
}
```

I know how to run just one file with

```
features = {"src/test/resources/features/AsiaUsersMutexTest.Feature"},
```

However, I want to run just the files starting with some string. Lets say files with prefix "AsiaUserTests". Something like the following

```
features = {"src/test/resources/features/AsiaUsers*.Feature"},
```

This results into `java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <*>`, so wondering if there is a way to do it as I couldn't find something like this in web.

Comment: Maybe tags help you? https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this running by adding `@Custom-Tag` on features file that I want to run and modified the config as follows.

package com.hero.selenium.test;

```
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import net.serenitybdd.cucumber.CucumberWithSerenity;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        monochrome = true,
        features = {"src/test/resources/features/"},
        glue = {"com.hero.selenium.test.stepdefinitions"},
        tags= "@Custom-Tag"
)
public class MainRunner {
}
```

Thanks @lojza for the guidance!